Why is initialization of inline/non-inline variables indeterminately sequenced?
int x = f();
inline int y = x;

It is unspecified whether y is zero or the value of x.
Note that x has ordered initialization and y has partially-ordered initialization (see [basic.start.dynamic] p1).
Since not both have ordered initialization, and since x does not have partially-ordered initialization, [basic.start.dynamic] p3.1 does not apply, and their initialization is indeterminately sequenced.
Since the author uses the wording "W does not have unordered initialization", it does not appear that ordered initialization is meant to imply partially ordered initialization, otherwise this could have been simplified.
The author also didn't write "if neither V nor W have unordered initialization", which would have sequenced x's init before y's.
Question
The way it looks, this design is intentional, but what is its purpose?
Why would you want initialization to be indeterminately sequenced in such a simple case?
The proposal P0386R2: Inline Variables does not explain this.
Consequences in practice
To name one example, the initialization of std::cout via std::__ioinit is indeterminately sequenced with respect to any inline variables that follow:
// included from <iostream>:
namespace std {
// ...
extern ostream cout;
// libstdc++ implementation detail; initializes cout:
static ios_base::Init __ioinit;
}

// then, in our own code, possibly a header:
inline int x = [] {
    std::cout << "awoo"; // possibly UB
    return 0;
}();


In C++ inline is only a there for the linker. Inline variables are always global (bad idea anyway). So I think you need a more concrete example, this example implies x is a global variable too. Read more on static order initialization fiasco. Link and startup order is undefined.

@PepijnKramer I know about the fiasco, but it's only half-relevant. When there is only one TU, initialization is usually predictable. If both or neither x and y were inline, x would be initialized before y. It's only that making one of them inline is (intentionally?) breaking these guarantees, and I'm wondering what the motivation behind that is.

Yes that part is indeed perplexing. And the initialization order is kind of defined in one TU.  My guess and it is only a guess is that the origins lie in "C", where inline would allow the variable to be inlined in code in special optimization cases

The situation can only occur if inline isn't really used in the way it should be, i.e. only if the inline variable is defined in a single translation unit instead of a shared header file. If it was defined in multiple translation units, then it could never appear after the object with ordered initialization (i.e. with a non-inline definition) in each of them, as that variable can only be defined in a single one.

@user17732522 You can have a header that contains #include <iostream> and then defines an inline variable, which guarantees that all definitions from <iostream> always appear before your own stuff. A user can reasonably expect this to work, and I don't believe this is using inline variables in a way they shouldn't be. If all definitions of A always appear before definitions of B, A is initialized before B, at least for inline variables. It's what makes it possible to have two inline variables initialized in terms of each other, so this is use as intended.

@JanSchultke Yes, ok. But it must be through an indirect side effect, not a direct dependence as in your example in this question. I agree that the effect on the standard streams is surprising, but I don't think it is a common situation otherwise.

@JanSchultke Ordering of two inline variables is covered by the current rules. Only the case ordered followed by partially-ordered is not.

Because
extern int x;
inline int y = x;

might appear in another translation unit and the compiler can’t be expected to know that y even appears in the translation unit that defines x.
If x has internal linkage, this logic doesn’t apply, of course, but then it’s impossible to define y in multiple translation units (aside from the old hack with a constant x) and it shouldn’t be inline.

Hmm yeah. I realize that I've read the wording a bit wrong. For any ordering of inline stuff to take place, the requirement is that for every definition of the latter variable, there must be a definition of the former variable which appears first. From the perspective of how inline variables are implemented, anything else seems impossible. You could still cut out a specific case where there exists only one definition of an inline variable, but that's kinda pointless.
